# Is Assignment Operator or Copy Constructor invoked for array/vector insertions?

Tags: c++

Language: C++

My question is about whether the copy constructor or the assignment operator is called in the following situations. To precede, I understand the following:

```
MyClass a(3);      // single param constructor
MyClass b(a);      // copy constructor invoked
MyClass c = b;     // copy constructor invoked
MyClass d;         // default constructor
d = c;             // assignment operator invoked
```

However, I was hoping someone could give a similar breakdown for these:

1) For lines 2-3, is assignment operator or copy constructor called?

```
MyClass arr[10];
arr[2] = a;
arr[5] = MyClass(1);
```

2) Constructor, then copy constructor? Or constructor, then assignment operator?

```
MyClass arr2[] = {MyClass(), MyClass(9)};
```

3) Assuming vector `v`'s internal representation has space for one more object, is new element copied using assignment operator or copy constructor?

```
std::vector<MyClass> v;
v.push_back(MyClass(2));
...
...
```

4) Assuming vector `v`'s internal representation is out of space and must realloc, are old elements copied using assignment operator, or copy constructor?

```
v.push_back(MyClass(2)); // Assuming vector is out of space; must realloc
```

Comment: 1) Can you find out yourself, by printing diagnostic methods in the relevant functions? 2) Are such answers implementation specific?

Comment: 1) You completely missed move construction. 2) How `std::vector` is resized depends on whether move constructor is not throwing.

Comment: A constructor is used for constructing. The assignment operator is used for modifying an object that's already been constructed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have

```
type variable_name = some_value
```

then you are declaring a variable and will always be calling its constructor (if it has one).  This is called copy initialization and this will never be assignment

So, in

```
MyClass arr[10];      // 1
arr[2] = a;           // 2
arr[5] = MyClass(1);  // 3
```

Line 1 creates an array of 10 `MyClass` and default constructs each of them.  Lines 2 and 3 are assignment.

In

```
MyClass arr2[] = {MyClass(), MyClass(9)};
```

You initialize an array of 2 objects using the values in the *braced-init-list` as the initializers for the array members.  There are many rules governing [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) but the one thing they have in common is no assignment will happen, only constructor calls.

With

```
std::vector<MyClass> v;
v.push_back(MyClass(2));
```

Assuming the vector doesn't reallocate, you have a constructor call for `MyClass(2)` and then the element in the vector is copy constructed from that temporary object.  If the vector has to grow then all of the current elements are copy/move constructed to a new buffer then the temporary is copied constructed at the end.

Answer (score 2):

```
MyClass arr[10];
```

Constructor for MyClass is called 10 times, as 10 objects of arr are created.

```
arr[2] = a;
```

Assignment operator is invoked, assigns `arr[2]` to `a`.

```
arr[5] = MyClass(1);
```

First single param constructor with parameter `1` is called and creates an object of MyClass. Then assignment operator is invoked.

```
MyClass arr2[] = {MyClass(), MyClass(9)};
```

Two constructors and only are called here. First the `Myclass()` and then "single param constructor" `MyClass(9)`. The array declaration with initialization is not an assignment, cause no existing arrays members exists to assign to.

```
std::vector<MyClass> v;
```

Constructor for `std::vector<MyClass>` is called.

```
v.push_back(MyClass(2));
```

`std::vector::push_back` creates a copy of the class and stores it. So first `MyClass(2)` constructor is called, then copy constructor `MyClass(const MyClass &)` is called to copy the value. Then the copied object is stored.

> Assuming vector v's internal representation is out of space and must realloc, are old elements copied using assignment operator, or copy constructor?

Copy operator is invoked for each member. So:

```
std::vector<MyClass> a;
```

Calls constructor for `std::vector<MyClass>`

```
a.push_back(MyClass(1));
```

Calls constructor for `MyClass(1)` and copies it using copy cosntructor `MyClass(MyClass&)`.
After that if we add another element to the array:

```
a.push_back(MyClass(2));
```

Then `MyClass(2)` constructor is called, then copy constructor is called for `MyClass(MyClass&)` for the just constructed `MyClass(2)` object. Then the vector copy-constructs all existing members from the ned, so for the pre-existing object in the vector `MyClass(1)` already upped copy constructor is called.

Really, play with it a little. And insert cout everywhere to see it:

```
struct MyClass {
    MyClass(int a = 0) : _a(a) {
        _count = count++;
        std::cout << __func__ << " " 
            << _count << " "
            << this << " "
            << this->_a << "\n";
    }
    MyClass(const MyClass &old_obj) {
        this->_a = old_obj._a;
        std::cout << __func__ << "Copy " 
            << _count << " "
            << this << " "
            << this->_a << " "
            << &old_obj << " "
            << old_obj._a << "\n";
    }
    void operator=(const MyClass &old_obj) {
        this->_a = old_obj._a;
        std::cout << "MyClass" << __func__ << " " 
            << _count << " "
            << this << " "
            << this->_a << " "
            << &old_obj << " "
            << old_obj._a << "\n";
    }
    static int count;
    int _count;
    int _a;
};

int MyClass::count = 0;
```